# Finding the coordinates of the point that divides the segment with ratio $\mu$

Tags: geometry

I want to know what I did wrong.

> For points $P_1,P_2\in \Bbb R^2$, the formulas to get the coordinates of the point that divides the segment $P_1P_2$ with ratio $\mu\not=1$, are: $$x=\frac{x_1-\mu x_2}{1-\mu},y=\frac{y_1-\mu y_2}{1-\mu}$$

I think this is what they are asking:

[image]

We have that this happens: $$\frac{P_1P}{PP_2}=\mu \Rightarrow P_1P=\mu PP_2 \Rightarrow (x-x_1,y-y_1)=\mu(x_2-x,y_2-y)$$
But with that I get: $$x=\frac{\mu x_2+x_1}{1+\mu}$$
the signs don't match!!!

On the other hand, there's a hint for the problem, use the following similar triangles: 
[image]

(I added the points $A,B$) But I don't know how to use the hint, I know that $$\frac{P_2B}{P_2A}=\frac{P_2P_1}{P_2P}=\frac{AP}{BP_1}$$
I don't see how that's helpful.

Comment: In your derivation note that the formula for distance between two points is incorrect.

Comment: @Macavity I suspect that is $\frac {P_1P}{P_2P}$ in that case the formulas make sense, but I don't see why, how am I taking it wrong?

Comment: There are two possibilities, the point you seek is in the segment, or outside. Check for eg http://www.math-only-math.com/division-of-line-segment.html for a detailed illustration of both cases.

Comment: Also note the distance formula is $\sqrt{(x_1-x)^2+...}$

Comment: @Macavity Thank you! that was very helful! I wish you posted some kind of answer so I could accept it :)

Comment: You're welcome. You could post the derivation as an answer yourself and accept it, so others may benefit.